# Viewpager2 zoom into content/Image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager2

Basically, Im currently working on an comic reader app. So far I have created an ViewPager2 and set it up to scroll. The main problem is that most images are very long and because of that you can see the whole image in very small because it tries to fit in the screen, is there a way to work around it?

This is for containing the ViewPager:

```
<com.alexvasilkov.gestures.views.GestureFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:gest_fillViewport="true"
    app:gest_fitMethod="inside"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- used for page dedection -->
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recylerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_pager"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    </FrameLayout>
</com.alexvasilkov.gestures.views.GestureFrameLayout>
```

The Image is in a seperate xml Layout:

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/page_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Have you tried to `android:scaleType` to the ImageView

Comment: yes, but they are not turning out how I want them to be.